# I'm trying to anchor a text node to the right of another text node

Tags: tikz-pgf, text, anchor

I'm trying to anchor a text node to the right of another named text node. At the top left corner should be "Mary read" (with a box around 'Mary'). Instead, the word 'read' appear to be to the right of (0,0).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(Mary)[draw] at (-3,2) {\Large Mary};
    \node[text] at[anchor=west] (Mary) {\Large read};

    \node[draw] at (3,-2) {\Large The book};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You should try to use unique node names. Also, you want to use the east anchor of the Mary node. `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large]
    \node[draw](Mary) at (-3,2) {Mary};
    \node[anchor=west](read) at (Mary.east) {read};
    \node[draw] at (3,-2) {The book};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Of course, there are many better ways, but if you really want to place those nodes manually next to each other, use `positioning`. `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large]
    \node[draw](Mary) at (-3,2) {Mary};
    \node[base right=0pt of Mary](read) {read};
    \node[draw] at (3,-2) {The book};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`